# How can I add space between the title and icon? in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How can I add space between the title and icon?

````
<div className="new-data_title">

{title},<icon icon={icon}/>

</div>

</Button>```
````

Comment: Add `&nbsp;`. As many as you like.

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way is to use

```
&nbsp; or &#160

{title} &nbsp;&nbsp; <icon icon={icon}/>
```

check this link for more details:
[https://blog.hubspot.com/website/html-space][1]